# Sort a List based on a Pre-Sorted List

Tags: c#, list, sorting

How can I sort a list based on a pre-sorted list.

I have a list which is already sorted. Say, my sorted list is

```
{"Junior Developer", "Developer", "Senior Developer", "Project Lead"}
```

Now, I want to sort any subset of the above list in the same order as the above list. That is, if I have as input

`{"Developer", "Junior Developer"}`, I want the output as `{"Junior Developer", "Developer"}`

If the input is `{"Project Lead", "Junior Developer", "Developer"}`, I want the output as

```
{"Junior Developer", "Developer", "Project Lead"}.
```

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Sort by `.IndexOf()`

Comment: Just to expand @zerkms comment: `input.OrderBy(x => bigSortedList.IndexOf(x))`

Comment: Maybe not the best formatted question, but a legitimate question all the same. Why the downvotes?

Comment: @cost I was wondering about the same, but the upvotes seem to have automatically taken care of. With regards to the formatting, I am more than happy if someone edited it to meet the standards and learn from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use LINQ's `.OrderBy` extension method, along with the `IndexOf` method (or equivalent) of your pre-sorted collection. The idea here is to sort using a different value as the "sort key" (this is quite useful, since often we'll want to sort objects based on one of their properties).

```
var sorted = listToSort.OrderBy(s => listPreSorted.IndexOf(s)).ToList();
```

And here's an example with arrays: http://ideone.com/7oshhZ

---

Note that if your lists are *very* large, this will likely be slow, since each item in your target list has to be sequentially looked up in your pre-sorted collection (`O(N * M)`, where `N` is the length of the target list, and `M` is the length of the pre-sorted list).

To overcome this limitation, you could generate a lookup mapping the items of your pre-sorted list to their indices, then use this lookup in your `.OrderBy` (this would have a runtime of `O(N + M)`, and you could re-use the lookup if needed):

```
var preSortedLookup =
        listPreSorted.Select((v, i) => new { Key = v, Value = i })
                     .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

var sorted = listToSort.OrderBy(s => preSortedLookup[s]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are **no duplicates** in either of the two lists then you can simply use `Intersect`, which will preserve the order:

```
var allRoles = new[] {"Junior Developer", "Developer",
                      "Senior Developer", "Project Lead"};
var roles = new[] {"Developer", "Junior Developer"};
var sortedRoles = allRoles.Intersect(roles);
```

That would probably be more efficient than sorting by `IndexOf` but you're not likely to notice much difference unless the lists are very long.

Comment: @Mathew: Didn't know that Intersect preserves the order. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a sorted list, listA, and the other list you would have is listB. 
every time you read from listB, check if the element is in listA, and based upon that order your list.

Answer (score 0):

if you get big load , try a dictionary?

1,

```
dictionary<string,int>
```

use this dictionary to store string and index

2, 
generate a `list<string> result` set length as your number of strings with Dummy data

3
then locate the proper index number
write the string into  `result` by index