# Sorting TCL lists by values in a pre-defined list

Tags: tcl

There's actually an existing question in C# for this, so hoping someone can give me the TCL solution. [Sort a List based on a Pre-Sorted List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875915/sort-a-list-based-on-a-pre-sorted-list)

I have a list which is already sorted. Say, my sorted list is

```
{"Junior Developer" "Developer" "Senior Developer" "Project Lead"}
```

Now, I want to sort any subset of the above list in the same order as the above list. That is, if I have as input

```
{"Developer" "Junior Developer"}
```

I want the output as

```
{"Junior Developer" "Developer"}
```

If the input is

```
{"Project Lead" "Junior Developer" "Developer"}
```

then I want the output as

```
{"Junior Developer" "Developer" "Project Lead"}
```

I see that `lsort` has a `-command` option, but have read lots of comments saying that it doesn't have great performance, so was wondering if there's another approach maybe using a `dict` to preserve the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lsearch` to get the indices into the sorted list and then use those as collation keys:

```
set orderList {"Junior Developer" "Developer" "Senior Developer" "Project Lead"}
set original {"Developer" "Junior Developer"}

set keyed [lmap value $original {list $value [lsearch -exact $orderList $value]}]
set sortedKeyed [lsort -index 1 -integer $keyed]
set sorted [lmap value $sortedKeyed {lindex $value 0}]

puts "$original -> $sorted"
# "Developer" "Junior Developer" -> {Junior Developer} Developer
```

Putting double quotes around the values is not recommended in the output; it's not a canonical list quoting style (and it is *hard* to force Tcl to do it; there are evil edge cases that don't usually matter when doing user-visible output).

---

You can instead use the `-indices` option to `lsort` to avoid having to build all those tuples.

```
set orderList {"Junior Developer" "Developer" "Senior Developer" "Project Lead"}
set original {"Developer" "Junior Developer"}

set indexes [lmap value $original {lsearch -exact $orderList $value}]
set sortedIndexes [lsort -indices -integer $indexes]
set sorted [lmap idx $sortedIndexes {lindex $original $idx}]

puts "$original -> $sorted"
# "Developer" "Junior Developer" -> {Junior Developer} Developer
```

---

You can use `foreach` instead of `lmap`, but the code is a lot more long-winded.

Comment: Dear Donal, thanks for this wonderful answer. A couple of questions:
1. do you have a preference for either approach? 
2. can you explain why you use `lsearch -sorted` and not `-exact`? I don't understand this bit?
3. Is this approach much faster than using some variation of `lsort -command`?

Comment: Oops. The `-sorted` option is wrong here. (It does a binary search and implies `-exact`.) I was hoping that the initial mapping could be accelerated (there are ways to do so when the sort order is defined over a longer list) but it only worked this time by happenstance. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks. Makes more sense now!